# How to disable tinymce after it is fully initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

Right now, I'm using this line of code to disable tinyMCE

```
tinyMCE.get('tinymce_id').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

However, it doesn't seem to be disabled on initialization. Only when I select the radio buttons then it will be disabled.

How do I disable specific tinyMCE editor after it initializes? If possible, I would like an answer which works for IE8 too. Thanks in advance!

---

**JQuery :**

```
 require(['tinymce'],function(){

            var disableInputs = function(){
                if($('input[name=type]:checked').val()==1){
                    tinyMCE.get('newsletter_message').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
                    tinyMCE.get('category_message').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
                }else{
                    tinyMCE.get('newsletter_message').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
                    tinyMCE.get('category_message').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
                }
            };
            $('input[name=type]').on('click',function(){
                disableInputs();
            });
            disableInputs();

        });
```

**HTML :**

```
<input type="radio" value=1 name=type/>
<div id="newsletter"> tinymce with id of newsletter_message initializes here... </div>

<input type="radio" value=0 name=type/>
<div id="category"> tinymce with id of category_message initializes here... </div>
```

Comment: `tinyMCE.remove();` ?

Comment: @KevinLabécot are you sure? i don't want to remove it. Just want disable it.

Comment: Well, Ok. I'm wrong ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in V6:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.hide()
```

and to turn it on again

```
tinymce.activeEditor.show()
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.editor/#hide

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `readonly` config param? According to TinyMCE doc (http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:readonly):

> This option enables you to specify make editor instances in readonly mode. When they are in readonly mode nothing can be changed and the contents are just presented to the user. You can use this in combination with body_class to present a different visual presentation for the readonly mode.

So, you could add something like (from the same source):

```
// Move focus to specific element
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        theme : "advanced",
        readonly : 1
});
```